# gdb breakpoint behavior between with and without *

Tags: assembly, gdb

I have a simple x86 assembly program

```
.data

  HelloWorld:
    .ascii "Hello World!"

  ByteLocation:
    .byte 10

  Int32:
    .int 2
  Int16:
    .short 3
  Float:
    .float 10.23

  IntegerArray:
    .int 10,20,30,40,50


.bss
  .comm LargeBuffer, 10000

.text

  .globl _start

  _start:
    nop
    # Exit syscall to exit the program 

    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

I compiled it and run it in gdb. Then I tried to set break point for

```
movl $1, %eax
```

I use:

```
(gdb)break *_start + 1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000b1: file VariableDemo.s, line 33.
```

This works fine. But if I tried:

```
(gdb) break _start + 1
Function "_start + 1" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
```

What is the difference between with and without * in this case? Also why does the second gdb breakpoint command ask me about shared library?

Answer (score 0):

break *_start + 1 puts a breakpoint at address of _main + 1. This is valid location.

There is no _function + something syntax for location in Gdb AFAIK. It is obvious it takes a whole "_main + 1" as a name of function (not sure what language allows that). So it looks for this "_main + 1" function and as it can not find it at that moment, it asks you if it should try again when/if some shared library is loaded later.

Valid ways to specify location are explained [in gdb manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html#Specify-Location).